# Importing CSV File in Elasticsearch

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana

I am new to elasticsearch. Trying to import CSV file by [following the guide](https://www.elastic.co/blog/importing-csv-and-log-data-into-elasticsearch-with-file-data-visualizer)

And successfully imported the file and it has created an index with the documents also.
But what I found that in every docs `_id` contains random unique id as a value. I want to have value of `_id` from the CSV file field (the CSV file which I'm importing contains a field with unique id for every row) using query or any other ways. And I do not know how to do that.
Even in docs it is not explained. A sample example of document of elasticsearch index is shown below

```
{
    "_index" : "sample_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "nGHXgngBpB_Kjkqcxfj",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "categoryid" : "34128b58-9148-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003",
      "categoryname" : "Blogs",
      "isdeleted" : "False"
    }
```

while adding ingest pipeline with the following query

> {
> "set": {
> "field": "_id",
> "value": "{{categoryid}}"
> }
> }

it throwing an error with [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpxOy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by modifying the ingest pipeline used to ingest your CSV file.

In the Ingest pipeline area (Advanced section), simply add the following processor at the end of the pipeline and the document ID will be set accordingly:

```
...
{
  "set": {
    "field": "_id",
    "value": "{{categoryid}}"
  }
}
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: throwing an error       [parse_exception] [processors] required property is missing, with { property_name="processors" }

Comment: Can you update your question with a screenshot of your ingest pipeine?

Comment: Just update your question so everyone can see

Comment: still waiting for exact solution

Comment: That's the exact solution, it should work. Can you show the full ingest pipeline please? Note that I didn't say to "replace" the ingest pipeline, but to add the above processor at the end of the pipeline

Comment: There was nothing such type of predefined pipeline (query) inside ingest pipeline section initially. Only "Index settings" section contains "number of shards" and "mapping" section contains my csv file fields. could you please send me your ingest pipeline query?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1zVuCOQ     this is my full ingest pipeline block

Comment: Ok, then you simply need to add a pipeline with the single `set` processor I mentioned. I'm running the latest 7.12 version, maybe that's the reason why my pipeline was different. The only important processor for what you want to do it the one I'm mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for query. It helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Added following processor in ingest pipeline section and it works..

```
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_id",
        "value": "{{categoryid}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```